# iOS iTunes Store app changed podcast page formatting

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts

The podcast page format changed recently. I was getting a format that listed the episodes in order and at right would be "download" button to download that episode to the Music app. Now it's a down arrow (but it does the same thing). I could press the episode title to listen, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. Also the new page format has a subscribe button that wasn't in the previous format. What's happened?

Was working as usual iTunes > Podcast then went to use an hour later and all podcasts are in the new format. I have no computer access and tried resets.

Comment: Are you using an iPhone or a PC/Mac? Is the issue in the Music app or the iTunes Store app?

Comment: iPhone 3g 3.1. iTunes app works same except podcast . Format has changed ( no updating or computer link up) .previously green box with download written now grey box with arrow. New format not working.

Comment: I don't see a Subscribe button on my iPhone 4S - can you add a link to a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes Store app uses a web view, so Apple can update the how the app looks remotely without touching your phone.

Since all podcasts are free, there's no need for it to look the same as the music purchases. Tapping the podcast title should still work to play it.